# How to focus UrhoSharp window when app starts?

Tags: c#, xamarin, urhosharp

UrhoSharp example app from UrhoSharp template for Visual Studio should exit when `ESC` key is pressed:

```
Input.SubscribeToKeyDown(args => { if (args.Key == Key.Esc) Exit(); });
```

However, it seems that it does not.

I have found that I need to click the app window first and then press `ESC`.
The problem seems to be caused that the app window doesn't have a focus when the app starts. (App's console window has focus when app starts.)

How to give focus to the app window in UrhoSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you starting the program via the debugger with F5? If so, then use Ctrl+F5 instead to 'start without debugging' and the templates main window should have focus.

I also usually set the mouse to visible as a default when starting on these projects via:

`Input.SetMouseVisible(true, false);`

Comment: Thx for the idea. It also works with debugging, when Visual Studio hosting process is disabled.